# Type 'NSNotification.Name?' has no member 'firInstanceIDTokenRefresh'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase notifications in my iOS app with Swift and I recently updated Firebase Messaging to 2 from 1.2.3 and my code started breaking left right and center. I fixed most of the issues, but I'm stuck with this one.

Here is my portion of AppDelegate application function which causing me problem:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    ...

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
    // [END add_token_refresh_observer]

    return true
}
```

When I try to run my app, I get the following error:

> Type 'NSNotification.Name?' has no member 'firInstanceIDTokenRefresh'

Has firInstanceIDTokenRefresh been renamed to something else?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It appears this notification has been replaced by a delegate method.

The [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) documentation mentions how to monitor token generation:

> Monitor token generation
>
> To be notified whenever the token is updated, supply a delegate conforming to the `FIRMessagingDelegate` protocol. The following example registers the delegate and adds the proper delegate method:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
```

**EDIT**

The docs also mention that the notification can still be used, it's now called `Notification.Name.MessagingRegistrationTokenRefreshed`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, no longer needed to listen to the NSNotification named `MessagingRegistrationTokenRefreshed`. The delegate method should be enough.